# how to send sms directly using intent to fix number with fix sms body

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

```
private  void  intentfun(String phoneNumber, String message) {

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+phoneNumber));
// smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);

smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",message);
startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

1) this is my code .when i run this code a build in massage window open up and shows massage api where user number and sms body is already filled up. this mssage in ready to sent.i have to click on sent button then this massage will be send to user's number. but i don't want this window. i want to send sms without showing user massage box where user number and sms body is already fill up. does it possible ?

2)

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent sentPI;
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);

        }
```

this code is also not working in my samsung s7562 mobile . i already define permission in project.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

when this code executed nothing happens, no error , no exception , no talk time balance deduction.

Comment: "i want to send sms without showing user massage box where user number and sms body is already fill up. does it possible ?" -- no. You are asking a third party app to do something. The third party app can do whatever it wants, based on what the developers of that app wanted to do. There is nothing in `ACTION_SENDTO` that allows you to request to block user modification of the text message, and even if there *were* such a flag, third-party apps can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
    String message = "Hello World!";

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

and paste this code in AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSSender {

    private Context context;
    private SMSData smsData;

    private enum ACTIONS {
        ACTION_SENT("SENT"), ACTION_DELEVERED("SMS_DELIVERED");

        String action;

        ACTIONS(String act) {
            action = act;
        }

        public String getAction() {
            return action;
        }
    }

    public static enum SMS_RESULT {
        SMS_SUCCESS, SMS_FAIL;
    }

    // private String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    // private String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    private BroadcastReceiver sendMessageRecevier, messageDeliveryReceiver;
    private Button btn;

    public SMSSender(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    private void init() {

    }

    public void setSMSData(SMSData data) {
        smsData = data;
    }

    public void send() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (smsData == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        sendSMS();
    }

    // ---sends a SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS() {

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(ACTIONS.ACTION_SENT.getAction()), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(ACTIONS.ACTION_DELEVERED.getAction()), 0);

        registerSentReceiver();
        registerDeliveryReceiver();

        // ---when the SMS has been delivered---

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        try {
            ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(smsData.getPayload());
            int numParts = parts.size();

            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
                sentIntents.add(sentPI);
                deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
            }

            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(smsData.target, null, parts,
                    sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

            Log.v("TEST", " Send sms phone  " + smsData.target
                    + " message " + smsData.getPayload());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sending SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void registerDeliveryReceiver() {
        messageDeliveryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                SMSResultReceiver receiver = smsData.getSMSResultReceiver();
                int result = getResultCode();
                if (receiver == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (Activity.RESULT_OK == result) {
                    receiver.onDelivered(SMS_RESULT.SMS_SUCCESS);

                } else {
                    receiver.onDelivered(SMS_RESULT.SMS_FAIL);
                }
            }
        };

        context.registerReceiver(messageDeliveryReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ACTIONS.ACTION_DELEVERED.getAction()));
    }

    private void registerSentReceiver() {
        sendMessageRecevier = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                SMSResultReceiver receiver = smsData.getSMSResultReceiver();
                int result = getResultCode();
                if (receiver == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (Activity.RESULT_OK == result) {
                    addToSentLog();
                    receiver.onSent(SMS_RESULT.SMS_SUCCESS);

                } else {
                    receiver.onSent(SMS_RESULT.SMS_FAIL);
                }

            }
        };

        // ---when the SMS has been sent---

        context.registerReceiver(sendMessageRecevier, new IntentFilter(
                ACTIONS.ACTION_SENT.getAction()));
    }

    private void addToSentLog() {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", smsData.target);
            values.put("body", smsData.getPayload());
            context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission under manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Use code below to send SMS

Note: below code will also support long messages and divide messages in parts to send SMS

```
       public void sendMessage(String number, String message) {
            SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String message = appPreferenceManager.getUserSelectedSafeModeMessage();
            ArrayList<String> parts = manager.divideMessage(message);
            manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null);
        }
```